# Ruby-on-Rails JavaScript not loading on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following JavaScript embedded into a Rails view, it works however it only loads when either the address is accessed directly by URL or the page refreshed not when visted by a link. eg hitting link `<a href="localhost:3000/searches/50">` will not display the table (but will display the rest of the page) but refreshing the page or typing `localhost:3000/searches/50` into the address bar will.

```
<script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
  function drawTable() {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', '#');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Actions');
    data.addRows([
        <% @items.each do |item| %>
            [ 
            <%= item.id.to_s %>, 
            '<%= link_to edit_item_path(item) do %>
               <i class="icon-edit"></i>
             <% end %>'
            ],
        <% end %>           
    ]);         
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('item-results'));
      table.draw(data, {allowHtml: true});      
   } 
</script>

<div id="item-results"></div>
```

Comment: If you're using Chrome, hit F12 to bring up the console, and go into the Network tab (or Firebug in Firefox, etc.). This will give you a detailed view of exactly what is being sent by your browser and the server response, including headers, etc. Also examine the server-side logs to see how the rails server is interpreting the calls. This should give some clues.

Answer (score 0):

Could be Turbolinks is interfering with the javascript. Try to turn it off and see what happens.